# How to preview workspaces?

Tags: 12.04, workspaces

Is it possible to preview workspaces? When I press down Ctrl+Alt+, it shows a preview of all workspaces until I release the keys. Is it possible see just the preview before having to switch?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try holding the `super/windows` key and press `S` this should do what you want.

Also holding the `super/windows` key will display a list of keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: thanks! I was looking for it in keyboard preferences and was lost.